# SetTimeout difficulty

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I want to make a script that allows my page to refresh in a random interval (between 15 minutes and 30 minutes).This is my code so far :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="startCount()">


<input type="text" id="txt" style="visibility:hidden;">

<script>
var c = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById("txt").value=c;
c = c+1;
if(c==10)  //if timer is 10 seconds ->refresh
location.reload();
t = setTimeout(function(){timedCount()},1000);
}

function startCount()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount()
{
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly if I keep the if like this `if(c==10)`, but to make the time random I modified it like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="startCount()">


<input type="text" id="txt" style="visibility:hi;">

<script>
var c = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount(number)
{
document.getElementById("txt").value=c;
c = c+1;
if(c==number)
location.reload();
t = setTimeout(function(){timedCount()},1000);
}

function startCount()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  var rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  timedCount(rand);
  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the second one won't work..And I don't know why..Please Help! :)

Comment: Where are max and min set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `max` and `min` variable assignments.

```
var min = 1;
var max = 10;
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

Example with alert(): http://jsfiddle.net/ZLcrX/

Example with jQuery DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLcrX/1/

Comment: Ohhh...I can't believe I posted this :))...Thank you..:)